# Find $ \left[ \sum \limits^{2006}_{k=1}\left( -1\right) ^{k}\frac{k^{2}- 3}{\left( k+1\right) ! } \right] -1$

Tags: summation, summation-method

$$ \left[ \sum \limits^{2006}_{k=1}\left( -1\right) ^{k}\frac{k^{2}- 3}{\left( k+1\right) ! } \right] -1$$
 My question is how I can get this summation in the closed form?. I tried to evaluate the summation . But I couldn't complete. How I can solve it?. Thanks

Comment: According to Mathematica the answer is $4.657805200972047\times10^{-5756}!$ (That's no a factorial sign; I'm just surprised.)

Comment: @DirkGently ok.  But I asked about the closed form

Comment: That's why this is a comment and not an answer. Please also remember that the comments and answers here are not only for the questioner but for anyone who might find the question interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The closed form is

$$\frac{(-1)^N (N-1)}{6 (4)_{N-2}}$$

for the upper limit of the sum $N$

i.e. for $N=2006$

$$\frac{(-1)^{2006} 2005}{2007!}$$

**Proof**
we can verify that the difference of this expression with itself with $N\to N-1$ gives the summand
$$
-\frac{(-1)^N N}{(N+2)!}-\frac{(-1)^N (N-2)}{(N)!}
=
\frac{(-1)^N \left(N^2-3\right)}{(N+1)!}
$$
and also the expression vanishes for $N=1$. So we get a proof by induction.

Comment: or $\frac{(-1)^N (N-1)}{(N+1)!}$ is a slightly better notations

Comment: Thanks for help.  But could you please explain How we get it?

Comment: need a little explain about.  How we get this? .

Comment: added a little explanation. Hope this helps!

Comment: A more practical explanation: type ${\rm Sum}[(-1)^k (k^2 - 3)/(k + 1)!, k]$ in mathematica